# Docker ENTRYPOINT doesn't execute command/ tox

Tags: docker, tox

Can anyone could give me a clue why I am not able run a command in ENTRYPOINT.
My Docker file looks like

```
.....
.....  
ENTRYPOINT ["bash -c tox -e docker-server"]
```

But when I do Dcoker run, I get this error

```
Docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash -c 
tox -e docker-server\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

Then I changed the command to ENTRYPOINT ["sh ls -l"], this time too I got any error

```
Docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"sh ls - 
l\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify each word in your command line in a separate element in the `ENTRYPOINT` array, such as:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c", "tox", "-e", "docker-server"]
```

Otherwise, docker will try to find an executable called "bash -c tox -e docker-server" and of course that doesn't exist.